# Running Wallet 0.8.6 with Parity 1.3.8 [Low # peers, Low speed]

Tags: mist, synchronization, attacks, parity, dos

Wondering why my blocks are processing so slowly. Peers ranging from 0 to 10. About 45,000 blocks behind... Processing 1 block about every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

You are not alone. The network was under [DoS](https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/09/22/ethereum-network-currently-undergoing-dos-attack/) [attacks](https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/09/18/security-alert-geth-nodes-crash-due-memory-bug/) for [several](https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/09/22/transaction-spam-attack-next-steps/) weeks. They spammed the nodes with special transactions exploiting too low gas costs for several operations.

Yesterday (Oct-19, 2016) was a [hard fork](https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/10/18/faq-upcoming-ethereum-hard-fork/) to mitigate that attack by [increasing gas costs](https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/10/13/announcement-imminent-hard-fork-eip150-gas-cost-changes/) for several operations. After block [2,463,000](https://fork.codetract.io/) your synchronization process will go back to normal.